# .NET Method Naming: when to use XXXFor and when to use GetXXX

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

When working with asp.net mvc, we'll see that there're lots of methods named with "For" suffix, such as `Html.EditorFor(...)`, `Html.TextBoxFor(...)` etc. These names are very intuitive and I like them.

My question is, when to use `GetXXX(...)` and when to use `XXXFor(...)`? It seems that even in the same framework, the naming of such methods are still not consistent. Sometimes `GetXXX(...)` is used while sometimes `XXXFor(...)` is used. Is there some naming principle on this?

**BTW**:

I'm curious about this is because I'm writing a class called `EntityKey`. I want to put two static methods in this class. They are `EntityKey.Get(object entity)` and `EntityKey.GetKeyProperties(Type entityType)`. But I'm thinking about to rename the `Get` method to `For`, so `EntityKey.For(object entity)`. If I renamed `Get` to `For`, I think it's better to also rename `GetKeyProperties` to `KeyPropertiesFor`. What do you think?

Comment: this question depends on language, could you please specify the tags

Comment: Thanks. I added language tags. I thought SO suggested tags will be automatically added, my bad :(

Comment: Coding style questions usually completely opinion based... Check out existing resources like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface and [.Net guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to influence your opinion one way or another.

Comment: do `GetEditor` and `GetTextBox` make more sense than `EditorFor` and `TextBoxFor`? I don't think so

Comment: These are just conventions. They have no effect on function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, the `xxxFor` methods aren't just a naming convention. That suffix indicates that the method operates on a property of the model.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName);
```

vs.

```
Html.TextBox("FirstName", @Model.FirstName);
```

Note also that these are not "C# Methods". These are .NET methods, part of ASP.NET MVC. They are named exactly the same if you use VB.NET.

Comment: This comparison make sense. Thanks :P. It should be ".NET Methods", sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "fluent" types of syntax are intended to make things more readable, so the biggest thing you want to ask yourself is which syntax best communicates what your code is doing.

Also, if you are simply retrieving data from entity classes, you might consider using extension methods.

```
public static int GetKey(this object entity)
{
    ....
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
someEntity.GetKey();
```

You could then take it a step further and have all of your entities inherit from a common interface and change your extension method to something like:

```
public static int GetKey(this IEntity entity)
{
   ...
}
```

It's possible that I am misunderstanding exactly what you are retrieving, but if it is some sort of data or metadata about a particular object, calling a method on the object that is the source of the data usually reads clearer to me.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks :) But John Saunders' answer provides a nice comparison which shows the key difference between the two naming methods. So I accept his answer.